Vertical CRS my Google Earth Engine code is outputting when I export to a CSV
I am using Google Earth Engine to annotate my movement tracks with high resolution elevation data. I am currently importing lat/long coordinates which have a horizontal crs=EPSG:4326. I am annotating the points with USGS/3DEP/10m which has a horizontal crs=EPSG:4269, and a vertical crs=EPSG:5703. Additionally when exporting/printing my results I specify the crs to be EPSG:4326.
Do you know if Google Earth Engine converts the horizontal CRS internally to be the same when annotating tracks? Additionally, do you know if Google Earth Engine does any conversions to the vertical CRS, or will it still export as EPSG:5703?
